# Trying to write regular expression to handle decoding of ID3v23 TCON value

Tags: java, regex

How do I write a regular expression (in java) to split strings from a TCON frame of an ID3 tag within an mp3 i.e http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0

Examples as follows (there is no max to how many terms there may be)

Input: `(1)(2)`

Ouput:

```
(1)
(2)
```

Input: `(1)Indie(2)`

Output:

```
(1)Indie
(2)
```

Input: `Indie Rock`

Output:

```
Indie
Rock
```

There are also two special cases of text that can be held in brackets (RX) and (CR) so

Input: `(RX)(CR)`

Output:

```
(RX)
(CR)
```

Comment: Closed as not real question, but I did update the original question with the real defined usecase I was trying to address (ID3v23 TCON frame) whihc I think could be useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replaceAll to make it comma (or other token) delimited then split:

```
str.replaceAll("(\\(\\d+\\)\\w*)", "$1,").split(",")
```

Comment: This assume that the text originally doesn't contains `,`.

Comment: Naturally, that's why I said any other token.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't read between the lines. It is better if you explicitly states your assumption.

Comment: Thx that worked, I changed to value.replaceAll("(\\(\\d+\\)\\w*)", "$1\u0000").split("\u0000") to avoid the ',' problem that was raised.

Comment: @nhahtdh thankyou, but i missed a usecase, could you possibley amend to show me how to handle (RX) and (CR) cases.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: You don't need to stick to the first answer you see. You are free to choose any other answer here that suits your needs.

Comment: @nhahtdh i know, but your regexp was the easiest to understand whihc is why Im using it, all the answers were posted before I added the additional usecase that I had forgotten.

Comment: Nevermind this seems to work value.replaceAll("(\\(\\d+\\)|\\(RX\\)|\\(CR\\)\\w*)", "$1\u0000").split("\u0000");

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
String[] arr = str.split(" |(?<=.)(?=\\(\\d+\\))");
```

`(?<=.)` means the last character was anything (thus not start of line).

`(?=\\(\\d+\\))` means the next characters are `(` followed by 1 or more digits followed by `)`.

**Note:** The above may be a little more complicated than it needs to be, you could simplify `(?=\\(\\d+\\))` to `(?=\\()` as in Kent's answer. It all depends exactly what you want to match.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] ss = str.split(" |(?<=\\S)(?=\\()");
```

the `ss` array holds the output segments.